# Как передать переменную в each ?

Tags: javascript

```
function MyFunc(e)
{
    $(".myclass").each(function(e) {
               // бла-бла-бла
    });
}
```

Как передать e в функцию?

Comment: вызвать функцию `MyFunc('ololo');`

Comment: @Palmervan, не вводите человека в заблуждение. Почитайте [документацию][1] по функции `each`. Там чётко прописано, что передаваемая в `each` функция - callback, который будет вызываться для каждого элемента коллекции, и в который будут передаваться два параметра - индекс и значение элемента в коллекции.

  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
function myFunc(e) {
    $('.myClass').each(function(text) {
        return function() {
            $(this).html(text);
        }
    }(e));
}

myFunc('test');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3z75X/

Comment: Но зачем?! Тут ведь не требуется дополнительное замыкание...